# initcall linker on ARM

Tags: c, linker, arm

I want to use an "initcall" system on an ARM CPU in C.

I define these macro :
typedef int (*payload_initcall_t)(payload_state_t *state);
extern payload_initcall_t __payload_initcall_start, __payload_initcall_end;

```
#define __payload_initcall(fn) \
        static payload_initcall_t __payload_initcall_##fn __payload_init_call = fn
#define __payload_init_call     __attribute__ ((unused,__section__ (".payload_init_ptrs")))
#define payload_init(x)  __payload_initcall(x);

#define __init __attribute__ ((__section__ (".code_segment")))
```

An example of module :

```
static int __init inspec_init(payload_state_t *state) {

    payload_log(LOG_INFO, "I AM THE PAYLOAD 1 !!");

    return 0;
}

payload_init(inspec_init)
```

The function which calls the modules :

```
payload_initcall_t *call_p;

        call_p = &__payload_initcall_start;
        do {
                payload_log(LOG_DEBUG, "payload init fct call: %p", (void *)call_p);
                (*call_p)(state);
                ++call_p;
        } while (call_p < &__payload_initcall_end);
```

In the linker file (just after .text section :

```
  __payload_initcall_start = .;
  payload_init_ptrs : { *(.payload_init_ptrs) }
  __payload_initcall_end   = .;
  code_segment    : { *(.code_segment) }
```

In my x86_64 computer it works.

I cross compile this code with a buildroot toolchain (GCC 7.4.0). The compilation terminates with no error but when I run the binary on the ARM target it segfault at the "(*call_p)(state)" line.
When I run objdump on the x86_64 binary I find "code_segment" and "payload_init_ptrs" but in the ARM binary I can't find these sections.
Is my GCC outdated ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `while` loop rather than a `do` `while` loop?

Comment: Oops. yes thank you. This is a mistake. It solves the segfault but not my problem.

Comment: Maybe the static stuff has been optimized away? You might need `__attribute__((used))` to keep them.

Comment: YES ! It works ! Thank you